# Смешанное меню Аккордеон + Drop down

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте, я в поисках меню [Аккордеон](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les209/example/index_collapsed.html) + [Drop down](http://vremenno.net/examples/css-drop-down-menu/simple.vertical.html).
Пробовал совместить их, но не смог, мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на Аккордеон выползали ссылки и при наведении на них всплывали дочерние ссылки, может такие уже есть, я не знаю, как гуглить, буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Установите аккордеон, и вместо содержимого пункта аккордеона (оно состоит из ul и li), вставьте код второго меню хтмл структура - у него такая же, а еще проще установить аккордеон, а для выпадающего меню написать небольшой скрипт, который бы показывал блок с подпунктом при хувере

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').show();
});
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я даже ховер правильно прописать в нужное месте не смогу)

Comment: Тогда, к сожелению, решение данной задачи не для вас